# Selenium : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am facing issue with Stale Element Exception. I already googled it and found some answers in stackoverflow, but neither worked. I came to know that this exception occur when the DOM element is destroyed and again created. Here my scenario is I have a table with records and there is a text below it like this, "Showing 1 to 6 of 6 rows". When I click on refresh button, this exception occurs.

```
String recordsBeforeRefresh = getRecordsCountFromTable(waitForElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("RefreshPage.Icon"))).getText());

        clickElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("RefreshPage.Button")), "Refresh");

        String recordsAfterRefresh = getRecordsCountFromTable(waitForElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("RefreshPage.Icon"))).getText());

        if(recordsBeforeRefresh.equals(recordsAfterRefresh))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

waitforElement is in another class like this

```
protected WebElement waitForElement(final By fieldLocator) {
        return waitForElement(fieldLocator, 30);
    }

protected WebElement waitForElement(final By fieldLocator, int timeoutSeconds) {

    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(getDriver()).withTimeout(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement field = null;
    try {
        field = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {

            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(fieldLocator);
            }

        });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new AutomationError(t);
    }

    return field;
}
```

getRecordsCountFromTable(String) has Regex pattern matching methods to fetch the total number of records.

Please help...

Stack Trace:

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 137 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
System info: host: '7YYCXY1', ip: '10.101.121.23', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\LSANAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6484_22708}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=47.0.2526.106, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: dd9a7e9b7d9d0f51a61f8075ed7bd843
```

The error is at String afterrefresh line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Lokesh S, You can try following steps, most probably to make it work:

Step 1: Click on Refresh or do the action
Step 2: Wait for the element to show up using explicit wait on the element
Step 3: **Do a findElement again on which StaleElementException is thrown.**

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("RefreshPage.Icon"))));
  try{
  recordsAfterRefresh = getRecordsCountFromTable(element.getText());
  }
  catch(StaleElementReferenceException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: `waitForElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("RefreshPage.Icon"));WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("RefreshPage.Icon"));getRecordsCountFromTable(element).getText());`